# Lodash equivalent of JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I am currently cloning an object with:

```
var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original));
```

When I try lodash - it seems the recommended way is cloneDeep() but that makes a total mess for me. My object is partially made up of the result of a Mongoose query which may be what is causing this.

Original:

```
template: 'email/receipt.swig',
templateVars: { 
  code: '299137819',
```

Cloneed with lodash:

```
template: 'email/receipt.swig',
templateVars: { 
  '$__': { 
    strictMode: true,
    selected: undefined,
    shardval: undefined,
    saveError: undefined,
    validationError: undefined,
    adhocPaths: undefined,
    removing: undefined,
    inserting: true,
    version: undefined,
    getters: [Object],
    _id: undefined,
    populate: undefined,
    populated: [Object],
    wasPopulated: false,
    scope: [Circular],
    activePaths: [Object],
    ownerDocument: undefined,
    fullPath: undefined 
  },
  isNew: false,
  errors: undefined,
  _maxListeners: 0,
  _events: { save: [Object], isNew: [Object] },
  _doc: { 
    code: '299137819'
```

What is happening here? This is clearly Mongo stuff but why the reformat?  Is there no way to make an exact copy with lodash? Not that my current method is a pain - just trying to understand why people say cloneDeep is the equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Objects returned from Mongoose are not raw key-values like you might expect from the DB, but they have a lot of other functionality build in.  Ultimately, [`cloneDeep` does this](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/cc9376c84320498431d2694d9b785691beddcc07/lodash.js#L1433), which ends up copying everything including functions and other stuff you may not want.

`JSON.stringify` as well as `.toJSON` will work [because of the `toJSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior) behavior.

So in fact they are not equivalent because you can redefine JSON serialization behavior and JSON *never* serializes functions anyway.

Comment: I understand that it may copy additional stuff but the structure is completely different. For ex `orig.templateVars.code` is now undefined which makes that kind of copy useless. Why the restructure? And is then no way for lodash to maintain structure?

Comment: Instead of doing a deep clone it's better to just use .toObject() to create plain, editable object from you Mongoose Document.